# Asymptotic inner expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, boundary-layer

Not sure if I should directly ask in the comment section of that thread or start a new thread like I have now. But anyway, I happen to come across this thread on MSE:

[Asymptotic Inner and Outer Expansion for a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723282/asymptotic-inner-and-outer-expansion-for-a-function)

and it deals with the inner and outer expansion of the function $$f(x,\epsilon) = \frac{e^{-x/\epsilon}}{x}+\frac{\sin (x)}{x}-\coth (x)$$

where $x>0$ and $0<\epsilon \ll 1$.

After trying this problem for myself, I found the outer region to be $x=O(1)$ with expansion $$f(x,\epsilon) \sim \frac{\sin (x)}{x} - \coth (x)$$

On the other hand, the inner region is $x=O(\epsilon)$, but when I tried to compute the inner expansion via the rescaling $x=\epsilon y$ where $y=O(1)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, I got

\begin{align}
\ f(x,\epsilon) & =F(y,\epsilon) \\
\ & = \frac{e^{-y}}{\epsilon y} + \frac{\sin (\epsilon y)}{\epsilon y} - \coth (\epsilon y) \\
\ & = \Bigl (\frac{e^{-y}}{y}\epsilon ^{-1} \Bigr)+ \Bigl(1-\frac{(\epsilon y)^2}{3!}+\frac{(\epsilon y)^4}{5!}+\cdots \Bigr)- \Bigl((\epsilon y)-\frac{(\epsilon y)^3}{3}+\frac{2(\epsilon y)^3}{15}-\cdots \Bigr)^{-1} \\
\end{align}

and we get a $(\frac{e^{-y}}{y}-\frac 1y) \epsilon ^{-1}$ term in the expansion even though we have assumed that $y = O(1)$.

How do I get around this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What different expectations do you have? Your calculations look good. And note that $\frac{e^{-y}-1}y=-1+\frac12y-\frac16y^2\pm\dots$, so that that term does not have a singularity in $y$.

Comment: But it is gonna blow up as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, since there is a $\epsilon ^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, with the pole of the $\coth$ you get $\frac{e^{-x/ϵ}-1}x\approx -\frac{e^{-x/(2ϵ)}}ϵ$ which starts at $-1/ϵ$ and falls (in size) to zero.